# Jquery fadeOut with this selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an element disappear when clicked, the elements are dynamic.

```
$("#toast-container").on("click", "div.toast", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
         $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I have tried the code with just `$(this).remove()` and it works but using fadeOut it doesn't. I have no idea why and it looks absolutely fine to me

Comment: try using hide() instead?

Comment: Seems to work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/6/

Comment: hide() works but it doesn't have the animation I'm looking for

Comment: You might wanna change the transition from 'fast' to 'slow' to see it in action : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a easy solution.

HTML

```
<div id="toast-container">
   <div class="toast">
      Click Me
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("div.toast").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("#toast-container").fadeOut('slow');
    // run your another event.
})
```

Check my live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/6x80vabm/9/)

Comment: So remove the parent. code is $(this).fadeOut('slow');

Answer (score 1):

well when adding elements dynamically to DOM tree i think your events may register at creation of the page but when you add an element dynamically  you should use another jquery function which is called delegate
[see the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: "on" is the new "delegate" :)

Comment: well i had a problem back in the day but on did not work for me so i used delegate i have more  experience with delegate :)

Answer (score -2):

What is this?

```
"div.toast"
```

If your div class is "toast", it should just be ".toast" (it will work with the div.toad, but syntactically, this is not really correct.

That said, your function works fine when I drop it in a fiddle. Are you certain that you are not getting any console errors perhaps related to another feature/function? Check your console.

Comment: I have no errors in my console and it only doesn't work with fadeOut(), I can use .remove() and .text() and it has the desired effect but fadeOut just doesn't work